# C: efficient encoding of code location

Tags: c

I wish to encode the location -- say, FILE/LINE -- each time I do a memory allocation. That's over 3,000 in my codebase, so I don't really want to hard code it.

I have used a macro which just passes in **FILE**, **LINE** which works great.

Now I want to store this with each allocation as well so it needs to get compressed. I have used a minimal perfect hash for **FILE** which makes the (FILE, LINE) pair fit within a 32 bit integer.

However, computing the MPH on each allocation is just too expensive (mostly because it loops through the string computing a primary hash first).
Since all the strings are constant, the MPH is constant and everything is constant, there should be a faster way to compute this.

Alternatively, does anyone know a better way to compute code locations so they can be looked up and stored in an efficient manner (I've looked at the boost library PP_COUNTER macro as well) ?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just compress the file after you're done?

Comment: Write a program which pre-preprocesses your code and injects a unique number in every call to an allocation function, plus produces a static table mapping the numbers back to the file,line pairs.  Then you don't need any hashing at runtime.

Comment: Add a static variable that contains `MPH(FILE)`, so it just gets calculated once per file. Then concatenate this with `LINE` when you do the allocations.

Comment: Is there really a problem with using `__FILE__` as is? The string is a literal (in C), which (in C99) is “_.. used to initialize an array of static storage duration_” and you pass in its address, which is all you need and need not be compressed. I have done it like this, with no problems (optionally including the current function), in VMS C, AIX C and MSVS C, and it has been very helpful. (I have seen that C++ function name macros may be function calls.)

Comment: @PJTraill Oh, that's clever, I should've thought of that myself.

Comment: P.S. In theory, a really poor compiler may not pool string literals, not even `__FILE__`, but that seems highly unlikely!

Comment: Barmar: not following either one of your suggestions.

Comment: zwol: that seems like really hard. We're talking over 2,000 files and sometimes it's not the caller you want, but the caller's caller, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**A code location is already efficiently encoded by `{ __FILE__, __LINE__ }`.**

The macro `__FILE__` expands to a string literal, which (in C99, and likely earlier) is “*used to initialize an array of static storage duration*” and you pass in its address, which is all you need and need not be compressed. I have done it like this (optionally including the current function name), with no problems, in VMS C, AIX C and MSVS C, and it has been very helpful.

N.B.

- In theory, a really poor compiler may not pool string literals, not even `__FILE__`, resulting in bloated object code, but that seems unlikely in the extreme!
- As long as your compiler does pool string literals, you can calculate a hash on the address, if you need one.
- I have seen that C++ function name macros may be function calls, so this technique may be inapplicable there.

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't sure about the pooling of literals, something I can follow up on.
The main concern is that this the combined total {__FILE__, __LINE__} is greater than 8 bytes. And there is no easy way to do MPH on this since the addresses are not known until run time.
So you'd either have to resort to hackery (because the addresses are likely to have the same leading 4 bytes or whatever) or a hash implementation with collisions and all that jazz to resolve.
Solvable, but a big PITA.